# Word similarity considering special characteristics

Tags: nlp, similarity

I'm looking for an algorithm that computes the similarity between two strings just like the `levenshtein` distance. However, I want to consider the following. The  `levenshtein` distance gives me the same for these cases:

```
distance("apple", "appli") #1
distance("apple", "appel") #1
distance("apple", "applr") #1
```

However, I want the second and third example to have a smaller distance because of the following reasons:

- second example: all the correct letters are used in the second word
- third example: `r` is much likely to be a typo of the letter `e` because of the keyboard placement.

Are you familiar with any algorithm that weights such characteristics ?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of versions of edit distance and plenty of possible extensions.

The edit operations can have different weights. By default, all operations have a weight of 1. However, you can easily reassign the weights of substitutions based on their distance on the keyboard and assign a lower weight for substituting neighboring characters. In Python, you can use e.g., [`weighted-levenshtein`](https://github.com/infoscout/weighted-levenshtein) package.

There is also an extension of the standard edit distance called [Damerau-Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance). It allows an additional operation of swapping two characters. If you set a lower cost for swapping characters, permuting characters in the string will be less penalized.

Comment: OK thank you very much. I will definitely have a look at this!